# Quotient groups of $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups

Suppose I am trying to show that a group $G$ is solvable and I gotten to having $Z(G)$ be a p-group and $G/Z(G)$. Now if I can show that $G/Z(G)$ is also a $p$-group, then both are solvable implying $G$ is solvable. Now intuitively it makes sense that $G/Z(G)$ is a p group, but how can one show it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but what do we know about $G$?  Could you tell us explicitly your assumptions and hypotheses? Thanks.

Comment: the only thing we know is that it is a p-group. From there we deduce that |Z(G)| > 1. And now we want to use, Z(G) and G/Z(G) to prove that G is solvable.

Comment: So you want to show that a $p$-group is solvable?

Comment: yes thats what i am trying to show

Comment: If you are assuming $G$ is a $p$-group, then any quotient of $G$ (and in particular $G / Z(G)$) will certainly be a $p$-group, since its order has to divide $|G|$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$G$ is a $p-$group, implies that $|G|=p^n$ for some positive integer $n$. $Z(G)$ is non-trivial and $Z(G)$ is also a $p-$group, implies that $|Z(G)|=p^k$, where $1\leq k \leq n$. If $n=k$, then $G$ is an abelian group, so solvable. If $n\neq k$, then $|G/Z(G)|=|G|/|Z(G)|=p^{n-k}$. Therefore $G/Z(G)$ is also a $p-$group.